# Contract.Requires not preventing a null reference warning (purple squiggly)

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I am specifying in the constructor that the params are not null. The fields are private and there is no other code existing for static checking to wonder whether or not these fields are getting set to null.

Nevertheless, I am getting a warning from Visual Studio 2013 that they might be null.

> CodeContracts: Possibly accessing a field on a null reference
>   'this.origin'

How can they ever be null? Is the static checker not able to figure this out, perhaps? Or am I not doing it right?

```
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

public class Link
{

    private Shape origin;
    private Shape destination;

    public Link(Shape origin, Shape destination)
    {
        Contract.Requires(origin != null);
        Contract.Requires(destination != null);
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public string OriginID()
    {
        return origin.ID; // getting purple squiggly here
    }

    public string DestinationID()
    {
        return destination.ID; // getting purple squiggly here
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

They are gone now. My question stands though, because I don't know what I did to make them go away. I did not change anything in this class nor the project settings. It's just, at the time I got the warnings, one of my tests did not pass and now, all tests pass. That's the only difference between then and now. The changes to make the test pass were in another class, not this one.

Comment: What's giving you a warning? ReSharper? Visual Studio itself?

Comment: Visual Studio -- don't have ReSharper any more :(

Comment: I think you need to add Ensures clauses to the ctor ensuring non-nullness. Or has this changed since the last time I used CC?! Try it.

Comment: @usr, good idea. when `Ensures` statements are added to the end of the ctor, it gives malformed contract. When added right after the `Requires` statements, same result.

Comment: Couldn't it just have been a hickup with VS itself? I mean it does act weird from time to time.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester, that's fine. But if it is, I'd like to know what step to take to slap it on the back or scare the crap out of it.

Comment: @toddmo sometimes the only way out is restarting it, unfortunately :) But you may have results just by re-opening a file for example.

Comment: What were the changes that made the test pass. You said *nothing* changed, and then you said you made changes elsewhere.

Comment: @MillieSmith, I implemented a method in another class, and that made the only failing test pass. The method did not use this class.

Comment: Did it use anything that uses anything that uses anything that uses this class?

Comment: @MillieSmith, Update: Yes, the method under test of the (now passing) test did reference the constructor of this class. It would be strange if usage of a class impacted warnings inside the class. What's the connection?

Comment: My guess is that the compiler picks up on whether the contract is possibly broken by any referencing code. I'm stabbing in the dark.

Comment: @MillieSmith, what's interesting is that now I have a test line that explicitly creates  a `Link` object with nulls in the constructor and no warnings appear anywhere lol. I'm going to post another question on that. That was the point of doing contracts, for me, was to get those warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependent upon your project settings, I do not believe the static checker is always able to work out the invariants on `origin` and `destination`.

There are several approaches which could be taken to resolve this warning:

**ContractInvariantMethod**

Add an explicit private method attributed with the `ContractInvariantMethodAttribute` and makes call to `Contract.Invariant`, e.g:

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void ObjectInvariant()
{
    Contract.Invariant(origin != null);
    Contract.Invariant(destination != null);
}
```

This will inform the static checker that these invariants will never be violated, i.e. `origin` and `destination` will never be null.

**readonly + Infer invariants for readonly**

Mark both of the fields as readonly and in your code contract settings, ensure the `Infer invariants for readonly` option is checked for the static checker:

[image: Infer invariants for readonly field screenshot]

I personally tend to go for the `ContractInvariantMethod` approach but also mark my fields as `readonly` if they are only initialised upon instantiation, both approaches should work however.

Comment: I like the readonly because it requires less adornment (nice word for clutter) in the class, and you are right, those fields should be read-only anyway!

Comment: @toddmo We all have our preferences; I like having the explicit method as a quick way to clarify the invariants of a backing field without having to check all initializations (e.g. overloaded ctors).